# SSL offloading from Apache to Tomcat get overwritten somewhere

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, debian-wheezy, tomcat6

I was asked to upgrade a server running Apache and Tomcat-6 on Debian Wheezy from HTTP to HTTPS.
I have successfully obtained and install SSL certificates on the Apache part and checked that they work (using two different SSL checkers).

Next, I have added the following block to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server.name
    Redirect permanent / https://server.name/
</VirtualHost>
```

and this to the end of the `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` block in the same file:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
```

On the Tomcat side, the `/etc/tomcat6/server.xml` file includes two active connectors:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now, when I go to `https://server.name/app/main/login.jspx`, I get an SSL connection, but it disappears after login. 
If I go to `https://server.name/app`, I am immediately redirected to `http://server.name/app/main/login.jspx` (no SSL). 
(And if I go to just `https://server.name/`, I end up on a redirect page defined in `/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/ROOT/index.html`.)

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to use the AJP proxy instead?

Comment: Try add `scheme="https" proxyName="server.name" proxyPort="443" secure="true"` in you  http connector (8080).

Comment: @FedericoSierra Thanks. This helped for the case where I connect explicitely via https, i.e., it stays as https. But the redirect from http to https still does not work.

Comment: Try add the redirect in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

Comment: @FedericoSierra Thanks, that did the trick :-). (I moved the `*.8`-related part (actually, only the `Redirect` line) from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and now it works. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: One more thing: I guess I should now use iptables to drop all connections to 8080 from outside of localhost, correct? And should I drop also outgoing?

Comment: listen on localhost is okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this Connector is being used in a proxy configuration, configure `proxyName`, `proxyPort`.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"
           scheme="https" 
           proxyName="server.name" 
           proxyPort="443" 
           secure="true" />
```

You will also need to set the `scheme` and `secure` attributes to the values `https` and `true` respectively for a https proxy.

For redirect http to https in apache server, try add directives in default config `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`.